# Truffle is installed but macOS cant find commands for any blockchain packages

Tags: installation, blockchain, nvm, truffle

[I opened terminal, I ran touch ~/.zshrc, then I downloaded nvm curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash

Once that was done, I chose nvm install 15.4.0 because it's the latest version. Woo whoo, it downloads. Everything is working great... I can even install truffle... I run that command. I type in truffle --version.. will you look at that.. it works... Okay, lets try running all of these same commands in a new Terminal. No. none of them work. Nothing works. I reinstall, over and over again. Still wont work. I touch the zshrc file and try doing it with bash instead, but why would I download truffle and nvm twice? why won't it run normally if I downloaded it without any issues. WHat's the problem here?
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vse72.png)

Comment: On the terminal that truffle is working, try finding out the path of truffle by running ```which truffle``` ,

Then open a new terminal, and ```echo $PATH``` to check if that path truffle is installed is inside your $PATH.

Comment: Please read and edit as described https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask